# RecyclerView's holder.getAdapterPosition() returns -1. Causing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to add an `OnClickListner` on a item inside `recyclerView` `adapter` the rest of the functionality is working good with `holder.getAdapterPosition()` but when am trying to implement `onClickListner` on it its showing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.
I am using `FlexboxLayoutManager`.

**My_Adapter_Class**

```
public class SuggestedSkillAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestedSkillAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public List<String> suggestedSkills;
public List<String> filterList;
Context context;
private int itemlayout;
FragOne fragOne;

public SuggestedSkillAdapter(int skill_badge_layout, List<String> suggestedSkills, Context context, FragOne fragOne) {
    this.itemlayout = skill_badge_layout;
    this.context = context;
    this.suggestedSkills = suggestedSkills;
    this.filterList = suggestedSkills;
    this.fragOne = fragOne;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemlayout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.skillName.setText(suggestedSkills.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        fragOne.addItemToSkillsToBeReviewed(suggestedSkills.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        suggestedSkills.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return suggestedSkills.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filterdNames) {
    this.suggestedSkills = filterdNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, suggestedSkills.size());
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.skillName)
    TextView skillName;
    @BindView(R.id.cardMain)
    CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

}
}
```

**Crash_Log**

```
`2019-04-03 11:04:10.774 18117-18117/com.example.addreview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-04-03 11:04:10.780 18117-18117/com.example.addreview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.addreview, PID: 18117
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=196; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
        at com.example.addreview.Adapters.SuggestedSkillAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0(SuggestedSkillAdapter.java:55)
        at com.example.addreview.Adapters.-$$Lambda$SuggestedSkillAdapter$ib8AJ50Na4r0wQZw7b9CrGCGhkY.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)`
```

Once I started getting the error am checking position on Toast message. But am calling the values of list from same method and values are showing up as expected. Unable to resolve why it's showing -1 as position.

I expect the exact position from `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: why dont you use position instead of getAdapterPosition

Comment: Can you show a CrashLogs?

Comment: show where do you fill your adapter.

Comment: is this problem occur after removing any items from the list ?

Comment: @PareshP. Added Crash Log. 

@SinaMN75 Am able to see the data and add that data in other lists on click but when I have added code to remove that data once added it's not working. 

@KevinKurien As I have read that it's a good practice to use `holder.getAdapterPosition`

Comment: @NullPointerException Yes while removing the item from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom listener inside your adapter and then fire the events upwards to an interface implementation defined within the parent. Your click logic should be handled within the containing Activity or Fragment.

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 // handle event inside onBindViewHolder  
 holder.someButtonToRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // some listener interface method
         onRemoveClickListener.onClick(view, position);
    }
});
}
```

[Attaching click handlers using listeners within the RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#attaching-click-handlers-using-listeners)

Comment: I don't know why but this helped and am able to do further operations. A bit of explanation would really help.

Comment: @kvaruna I have updated my answer, please refer the link for better understanding. Also please make sure that if you'd want to setup click handlers for views within your RecyclerView you need to define the click logic within the containing Activity or Fragment

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing dataSet operations on `onBindViewHolder()`. *It returns `-1` because `recyclerview` is calculating layout measurments.*

Even the `ClickListeners` should be defined inside ViewHolder class, because `onBindViewHolder()` gets called all the time, So view operations will be expensive when we talk about performance aspects.

**Suggestion:**
Move you entire `onClickListener` code snippet to `ViewHolder` class and see what happens. Use `getAdapterPosition()` method of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to get the current position of View.

Comment: I found your suggestion and explanation useful but the same thing happening even after shifting the `onClickListner` to `viewHolder`.

Comment: Okay, What is your line number 55?

Comment: The ViewHolder class. What about that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'position' value you are receiving from onBindViewHolder instead of getAdapterPosition().